# How Do I Create A Subscription WiFi Network (like Starbucks)

Tags: dhcp, wifi, apple-ios

When using an iPad, connecting at a Starbucks, you will see a page pop up (like a web browser, but with no address bar), and it will allow you to login.

Apple has a KB article on them at:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3867

However, I can't find any information on what configuration is required to emulate this. (i.e. a DHCP option, DNS setting, etc...)

Does anybody know how to make this happen on my wifi network?

Comment: "Captive Portal" is the term you need to research.

Comment: If anybody finds this, the way it works is by checking a file on apple's server to see if there is a redirect. So, a captive portal would work, but redirecting that one request would do it exclusively for ios devices.